# How to use partial views

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm coming to a part in my MVC 3 page where I need to do a JQuery $.Ajax callback, but unlike before where I have returned some simple values and handled updating the UI using JQuery I need to refresh the part of the page that displays the main ViewModel data. So in effect it's almost as if I need to do a callback but instead of returning the JSonResult I want to return the original View?? I'm pretty sure though that I need to be thinking about using partial views? Could anyone advise or perhaps point me towards a good tutorial?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want to get the full view, then call the action again via jQuery and replace a section of the HTML with a partial version of the same view?

Comment: Yes, kind of self explanitory really. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly. In this sort of scenario I usually re-use the same action but return either a full or partial view based on the IsAjaxRequest method.

```
    public ActionResult MyAction(string someParam)
    {
        //...

        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return PartialView(model);
        }
        else
        {
            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

This can then be called in jQuery using something like:

```
$("a.myAction").click(function (event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    var button = $(this);

    // Get more results using ajax
    $.get(button.attr("href"), function (data)
    {
        // Add the new content 
        $('div#myActionResult').empty().html(data);
    }, "html");
}
```

You may need to POST instead or change the Url to include a query string if you want to send data to the action to change the view.

Comment: OK thanks, not sure I properly understand from this example. I notice you are returning PartialView from the Controller action method with just the model, how does it know what PartialView you want to re-render?

Comment: It determines it based on the Controller and Action names (If you add a view, it will place it in a folder matching the controller and use the action name as the name of the view). You can optionally add a string argument to the View/PartialView method to provide the view name.